# script tags inside vue template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

there.
I am trying to add stripe checkout form through VUE Js template.

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
 class="stripe-button" 
 data-key="pk_test_api_key"
 data-amount="2000"
 data-name="1234CPM"
 data-description="2 widgets"
 data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png" 
 data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

But whenever I try to include this form element through vue template, it gives error stating **"- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as `<script>`, as they will not be parsed.
"**.

It would be very helpful if I could get a way to solve this. Any suggestion would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://github.com/matfish2/vue-stripe?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. It is quite not exactly to what I am looking. I used stripe element attribute and have to submit other api-request on success full payment .

Comment: There is an issue while I tried using the above github project.Whenever I try to run "yarn run dev" it gives me above error.
And "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. " error on the console.

I tried with adding "import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe';" and
export default { data: () => ({ //options }), components: { 'stripe-checkout': StripeCheckout }, } in one of my vue file.
Is there anything wrong I did here?

Comment: did you fix this problem? I'm using vue by including cdn. at this point can I use npm library like vue-stripe?

Comment: Yes, I fixed this problem. I used stripe's individual fields attributes for the payment form and integrated into its payment api endpoint.